# Stored procedure for normalizing and creating multiple new tables using existing data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, normalization

There is a table that is not normalized. I want to normalize it and nicely separate out the data into multiple tables while creating references, all done with a stored procedure.

The table that is not normalized:

---

`Murder`

(`CaseID`, `GunManufacturer`, `GunName`,`Villian`)

*Some sample data:*

```
(40465893, 'BIG COMPANY','AK47', 'Dank Hank')

(34534566, 'SMALL COMPANY','Bazooka', 'King Kong')
```

---

Now here are the tables I want to create and separately push this information into.
Note these tables (with constraints) have already been created and only the data needs to be added.

```
`Event`
(

    `VillianId`,    `GunId`, `date`,

    PRIMARY KEY (`VillianId`)

    FOREIGN KEY (`VillianId`) REFERENCES `Villian` (`VillianId`) 

    FOREIGN KEY (`GunId`) REFERENCES `Gun` (`GunId`)

    ) ;
```

---

```
`Gun`
(
    `GunId`,`ManufacturerId`,`GunName`,

    PRIMARY KEY (`GunId`),

    FOREIGN KEY (`ManufacturerId`) REFERENCES `Manufacturer` (`ManufacturerId`) 

) ;
```

---

```
`Manufacturer`
(

    `ManufacturerId`, `ManufacturerName`,

    PRIMARY KEY (`ManufacturerId`)

) ;
```

---

```
`Villian`
(

    `VillianId`, `VillianName`,

    PRIMARY KEY (`VillianId`)

) ;
```

---

Please ignore the syntax's in the question. Just wanted to make it easy to read. The Id's must be auto-generated as none currently exist in the single table. I've never made this kind of stored procedure before and just look for some guidance. Not expecting a complete solution. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the event date come from? There's no date in your original murder table. Note that introducing surrogate identifiers isn't normalizing. Extracting the transitive functional dependency `gun -> manufacturer` into a separate table (whether identified by ids or names) is, though.

Comment: Apologies, assume that information was there in the original table. My main question is how does a SP of this nature work? Can you give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that may do what you need:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE `UnpackMurder`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Manufacturer (ManufacturerName)
    SELECT DISTINCT GunManufacturer
    FROM Murder;

    INSERT INTO Gun (ManufacturerId, GunName)
    SELECT DISTINCT mf.ManufacturerId, md.GunName
    FROM Murder md
    JOIN Manufacturer mf ON md.GunManufacturer = mf.ManufacturerName;

    INSERT INTO Villian (VillianName)
    SELECT DISTINCT Villian
    FROM Murder;

    INSERT INTO `Event` (VillianId, GunId, `date`)
    SELECT v.VillianId, g.GunId, md.`date`
    FROM Murder md
    JOIN Manufacturer mf ON md.GunManufacturer = mf.ManufacturerName
    JOIN Gun g ON mf.ManufacturerId = g.ManufacturerId AND md.GunName = g.GunName
    JOIN Villian v ON md.Villian = v.VillianName;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```